# How can I search 360,000 files, about 280 GB?

Tags: macos, search, command-line

I have a folder (technically in this case, a read-only mounted disk image) containing a ton of data I got by running Data Rescue (a data recovery app) on one of my large server drives. I did several different scan types and dumped all the files into one place. Data Rescue 'reconstructs' deleted files and often doesn't get it quite right. It can miscategorize the type of file it is, and it can mash separate files together.

I am seeking two specific PHP files (and maybe about 5 others if I get lucky). Most of these recovered files don't have names (0002, 0003 etc), so I have to search by content.

I've come up with 6 different strings that should be able to identify these specific files. So I need a way to search the contents of files, not in an Apple "magic search" kinda way, but in an old school "manually read through every file looking for a string-match" kinda way.

`grep` sounds like the obvious choice, but it's been nothing but problems. grep can search recursively, and it can decompress gzip, zip and bzip archives, which is all good. But after a few minutes of running, it starts streaming "too many open files" errors. I'm not sure why, it's as if grep doesn't close a file after it opens it to search in it. I've also had issues with `grep` just stopping... not quitting, not crashing, not going unresponsive, but not using any more CPU, not reading anything from the disk, just sitting idle when it should be searching. I ALSO had trouble running multiple `grep` searches at once. `grep` seems to load files line by line, so something like a disk image gets the entire thing loaded into memory before searching. But there is only one file in this whole bundle that is larger than the amount of RAM I have. So as long as I do one `grep` at a time, I should be fine.

This is the command I'm using (wrapped in a script that does several commands to different output files, with some status outputting):
`zfgrep -l -r -a -J -i -s -U -n "#32cd32" /Volumes/\'Storage\'\ Original\ Recovery > 32cd32.txt`

This will run for a while, then it will hang. I'll get some results but not a full search. If I remove the `-s`, I get the flood of `too many open files` errors. Then, at someone else's suggestion, I use `find` to feed files to `grep` one at a time, like so:

`find /Volumes/\'Storage\'\ Original\ Recovery -exec zfgrep -l -r -a -J -i -s -U -n "#32cd32" {} \; -print > 32cd32.txt`

But that command has the exact same problems.

So this leaves me stuck. How can I search every single file on this disk image, including the archives, for some plain text strings. Including binary data files that may have been incorrectly merged with plain text files? This doesn't seem like that tough of a task for a modern multicore computer with a current OS, lots of RAM and a SSD.

I actually would prefer a GUI option, but at this point I'll take any solution that works.

Also I originally started trying to do this using BBEdit, but it was skipping a LOT of filetypes even when you tell it to search all files. Even files that are XML based. I was very surprised by this.

Comment: `grep` is the way to go here. Are you sure `grep` is the issue here? What happens if you run `find /... -print`, does it run through or terminate as well? And you definitively shouldn't get `too many open files` if you use `find ... -exec grep` so can you please, for both commands, copy/paste directly from Terminal so we see what you see?

Comment: Ah, you don't need `grep -r` if you use `find`, otherwise you traverse the subdirectories twice (and get the error from `zfgrep` ).

Comment: May sound a bit counter-intuitive, but try by creating an Xcode project, add all the files and use Xcode's built in search. Apple has repeatedly claimed how Xcode text searching is multiple times faster compared to grep. Also, I am not sure and assuming that Xcode shouldn't hit problems that you have mentioned.

Comment: @NimeshNeema Don't know how good Xcode works with binary files though

Comment: @nohillside testing without the -r now, ill be kind of amazed if that's all it turns out to be. Also added `-type f` to the find command so it skips directories.

Comment: A few minutes didn't get any too-many-files errors. So I'm going to let the full shell script run while I sleep without the -r's. So I'll be back with a followup in about 12 or so hours...

Comment: @NimeshNeema I gave `Xcode` a try but I know so little about it, I didn't get far. I did try dumping all the files in, but it was attempting to index them all. An index based search won't work for this because the type of content I'm looking for will most likely not get indexed, as they're not real 'words'. Plus I dropped 370,000 files in there but it was only scanning 30,000 of them. Clearly I'm way out of my element there, but hopefully this `find/grep` thing works.

Comment: You should remove the `-print` primary from your find statement. It is just repeating the results of `grep`.

Comment: Seems to be working. I guess that stray -r was causing all of my problems!

Comment: It sounds like your problem has been solved. I was going to suggest EasyFind because it has nice features to narrow your search but I guess it most likely uses 'find' and 'grep' as well. EasyFind is free at the MacApp Store.

Answer (score 1):

Using `find ... -exec grep -r` effectively traverses the whole directory several times (once as part of the `find`, once as part of each `grep -r`) which may lead to the errors you see. So you should either get rid of the `find` or the `-r`. As you use the `grep` part to identify the files to be collected, it's probably the `-r` in your case.